# How to show the name of the section at the first page of this section

Tags: fancyhdr

I want to show the name of the section in my book on the left side of the top of the first page only of this section. For example, in the screenshot below I need to show the name of the section at the left top of this page only (whereas the following pages show the name of the subsection). I use this code to show the name of the subsection at left top and it works fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{footskip=10pt, headheight=100pt, headsep=20pt, bottom =7mm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
```

Can any one help me to show the name of the section as well in the first page only of the section preceded by the symbol of the section?.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a minimal, but complete code showing the problem?

Comment: I edited the post @Bernard

Answer (score 0):

The default of `fancyhdr` for `\sectionmark` with `article` and it's default `oneside` is:

```
\def\sectionmark#1{%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\z@
          \thesection\hskip 1em\relax
        \fi #1}}
    {}
}%
```

Important is the empty second argument of `\markboth`. This means, the right mark is cleared. And because `\rightmark` used the *first* right mark of the page, in your case `\rightmark` returns that empty mark.

With:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{footskip=10pt, headheight=100pt, headsep=20pt, bottom =7mm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mwe}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markboth
    {\MakeUppercase{\ifnum \value{secnumdepth}>0
          \thesection\hskip 1em\relax
        \fi #1}}
    {\MakeUppercase{\ifnum \value{secnumdepth}>0
          \thesection\hskip 1em\relax
        \fi #1}}
}%
% as long as option twoside is not used, alternatively you can use:
% \renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
%   \markright
%     {\MakeUppercase{\ifnum \value{secnumdepth}>0
%           \thesection\hskip 1em\relax
%         \fi #1}}
% }%


\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

You would have an non empty right mark for all sections. So it shows the section, whenever the section is the first heading of the page, e.g.:

[image]

If you instead want the last left mark of the page, only if the right mark is empty, you can use:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{footskip=10pt, headheight=100pt, headsep=20pt, bottom =7mm}

\usepackage{scrextend}% provides \Ifstr etc.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mwe}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\Ifstr{\rightmark}{}{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markboth
    {\MakeUppercase{\ifnum \value{secnumdepth}>0
          \thesection\hskip 1em\relax
        \fi #1}}
    {}
}%
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If you don't want the section mark in upper case, either use `\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase …}` or remove the `\MakeUppercase` from the examples above. I would suggest the first one, because this also works, e.g., for the table of contents.